# Checking whether a table is geographic or not ...?

Tags: pyqgis

What is the best generic method to check whether an opened table is **geographic or not** using PyQgis ?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question...are you referring to the data and geographic coordinates? or are you referring to whether the table has an associated spatial  element e.g. dbf in a shapefile?

Comment: @spk578 Not sure to follow yours either ... lol ...  i would answer : the second part of your question (whether the table has an associated spatial element ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `hasGeometryType()` method from [QgsVectorLayer](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#ab8a1a3af1410c5ddc9b066b832e13fa9).

To examinate whether the selected layer has an associated geometry you can run this code in the QGIS Python console:

```
iface.activeLayer().hasGeometryType()
```

If it is `True`, the layer has a geometry (i.e., it's an spatial table). If it is `False`, the layer is a table (i.e., the table is non explicitly spatial).

Comment: Yes ... in fact at first glance i thought that was not a very "generic" solution since it is only a method from QgsVectorLayer ... but then i noticed that when u open (for example) a .csv file it is considered as a QgsVectorLayer ... so this solution is working for me so far ...